# difference between LSTM(512) and LSTMCELL(512)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, encoder-decoder

Checked the source code but still struggling to find the difference between tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512) and tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(512)

In many articles of encoders-decoders, at the encoders LSTM(512) is used and at decoder LSTMCell(512) is used.

What is the difference between the two? and why the encoder and decoder have such a difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A **cell** object is a part of a recurrent layer. The **recurrent layer** controls the cell and does the actual recurrent calculations, whereas the **cell** contains the main code for **each step's calculations**.

Both are almost same, from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/759174064b28851577a8489f464f4575c09d770c/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1959), you can see that `LSTMCell` is a part of the `LSTM` Layer.

`LSTM` is a recurrent layer.

An `LSTMCell` is an object used by the LSTM layer that contains the calculation logic for one step.

In encoder-deoder networks,

- `LSTM` is used in encoders because the output at each time step is discarded.
- `LSTMCell` is used in a decoder because, it processes a single word at every time step.